# How do I get terraform to read comma delimited json file?

Tags: json, terraform

I am trying to get terraform to pull multiple entries in my json file.

Json looks like this.......

```
"data":
    [
    {"name": "name-of-server", "region": "us-east", "role": "could-be-tag-or-else",      "create_app": true},
    ]
```

My Terraform main.tf currently looks like this.

```
locals {
    # get json 
    json-data = jsondecode(file("all-windows-machines-full.json"))

# get all windows
    windows-machines = [for data in local.json-data.data : data.name]
}
 output "windows-machines" { 
 value =  local.windows-machines
 }
```

The output only shows list of the name-of-servers.

If I want to add in region what do I need to put in main.tf?

Appreciate any help.

I have tried multiple adding input option and variables. I am new to terraform and still learning.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file

Comment: What is the desired output? Please edit the question to show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you understand your JSON input, the format you provided is a "[list](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#lists-tuples)" (aka "tuple" or "set") of "[objects](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects)". If you want to know the differences between these terms, I'd recommend you [the official and very clear documentation here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#collection-types).

### Raw object ("as-is")

In order to recreate an object from your list of objects, do not restrict your new object to only `data.name`. Instead, use your full object, like this :

```
locals {
    # get json 
    json-data = jsondecode(file("all-windows-machines-full.json"))

    # get all windows
    windows-machines = [
        for data in local.json-data.data : data
    ]
}
```

You'd get an output like this :

```
user@laptop:~/terraform/console$ terraform console
> local.windows-machines
[
  {
    "create_app" = true
    "name" = "name-of-server-00"
    "region" = "us-east"
    "role" = "could-be-tag-or-else"
  },
  {
    "create_app" = false
    "name" = "name-of-server-01"
    "region" = "eu-west-3"
    "role" = "could-be-tag-or-else"
  },
]
```

---

### Custom built object

If you don't want all properties to be part of your final object, you could also build it in the `for` loop :

```
locals {
    # get json 
    json-data = jsondecode(file("all-windows-machines-full.json"))

    # get all windows
    windows-machines = [
        for data in local.json-data.data : {
            name   = data.name
            region = data.region
        }
    ]
}
```

That would give you :

```
user@laptop:~/terraform/console$ terraform console
> local.windows-machines
[
  {
    "name" = "name-of-server-00"
    "region" = "us-east"
  },
  {
    "name" = "name-of-server-01"
    "region" = "eu-west-3"
  },
]
```

If you want to learn more about loops, I would also recommend you the documentation here : https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for and [the other expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions) you can use in Terraform. ;)

Comment: @Todd M, if the answer fulfill your needs, mark it as "Accepted" ;)